# I always get this error when creating a Kivy app

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to make a simple app made from Kivy on Windows:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

(EDIT) But each time I get this very long error; this is all of it:

```
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in  C:\Users\danie\.kivy\logs\kivy_16-07-15_5.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015, 20:20:57) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO              ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
[INFO              ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO              ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.4.0 - Build  10.18.15.4271'>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 530'>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 4
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.40 - Build 10.18.15.4271'>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO              ] [Shader      ] fragment shader: <b"WARNING: 0:6: '' :  #version directive missing">
[INFO              ] [Shader      ] vertex shader: <b"WARNING: 0:6: '' :  #version directive missing">
[WARNING           ] [Image       ] Unable to load image <C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\data\glsl\default.png>
[CRITICAL          ] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider at all!
sdl2 - Exception: SDL2: Unable to load image
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 67, in core_select_lib
     cls = cls()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 138, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 722, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 255, in create_window
    super(WindowSDL, self).create_window()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 897, in create_window
    self.render_context = RenderContext()
  File "kivy\graphics\instructions.pyx", line 756, in kivy.graphics.instructions.RenderContext.__init__ (kivy\graphics\instructions.c:10729)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 512, in __init__
    self.filename = arg
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 700, in _set_filename
    mipmap=self._mipmap, nocache=self._nocache)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 430, in load
    im = loader(filename, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 198, in __init__
    self._data = self.load(filename)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\img_sdl2.py", line 42, in load
    raise Exception('SDL2: Unable to load image')

[CRITICAL          ] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
 Exception ignored in: 'kivy.properties.dpi2px'
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\utils.py", line 513, in __get__
     retval = self.func(inst)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\metrics.py", line 175, in dpi
     EventLoop.ensure_window()
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 126, in ensure_window
     sys.exit(1)
 SystemExit: 1
[CRITICAL          ] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

I can't understand why this error is appearing, can you help me out of this?

Comment: Post the full log.

Comment: Sorry, now its the full one.

Comment: Do you have SDL installed?

Comment: It's a dependency that Kivy relies on. http://www.libsdl.org

Comment: can you find me a download for it? I prefer pip

Comment: whitch download? there a couple

Comment: downloaded it. What next?

Comment: I wonder if you have a path echo from before installation of gstreamer(`echo %path%`), because this is related to missing sdl2 binaries on the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the installation instructions say `gstreamer` is optional I had to install it to get kivy to work (windows). As on the installation page:
`python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/packages/simple/`

(uninstalling reproduced the error above, installing it again fixed it again)

Comment: If you are getting an error when you try to install gstreamer, you can download it directly from this link: https://kivy.org/downloads/appveyor/deps/gstreamer/

Then, you can install it directly in its folder with: python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer-0.1.5-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl     (Or, whichever version of gstreamer you downloaded.)

Answer (score 3):

The gstreamer suggestion was misleading in my case, since it seems it was fixed before 1.9.1 version I'm using. The error is documented in a little obscure pass of the documentation [here](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-windows.html#alternate-installations):

> If kivy was not installed using the wheels method these commands will not work and e.g. kivy.deps.sdl2 will fail to import. Instead, one must find the location of these dlls and manually pass them to the Tree class in a similar fashion as the example.

Basically it's a binary / dll issue on Windows caused by the fact I'm not using the "wheels method" (aka I've used a virtualenv and done my pip install there). I've fixed this way:

1. Locate the python share folder on windows. E.g. in a virtualenv you will find it on X:\virtualentpath\share
2. Copy the glew and sdl2 directory
3. After you've done [step 2 here](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-windows.html#packaging-a-simple-app) and before step 3, in the dist folder create a *share* folder and paste *glew* and *sdl* directories in it
4. Add the libraries path to the myappname.spec file

   ```
   coll = COLLECT(exe,
   Tree('dist\\share\\glew\\bin\\'),
   Tree('dist\\share\\sdl2\\bin\\'),
   Tree('c:\\Users\\myuser\\PycharmProjects\\myappname\\'),
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          name='myappname')
   ```

If you need gstreamer you have to add it, **if you don't need you haven't**. It's important because the only gstreamer library is something like 44 times larger than the basic two:

- glew + sdl = 7.31MB
- gstreamer = 323MB

I don't know if it's the right method but after I stumbled on a red herring after another in several hours this is the *only* method that works in my case.

Rewriting that last paragraph in the Kivy documentation will help in this cases on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on @chirale 's answer, this is based on https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html, but for --onedir instead of --onefile method. This adds at `COLLECT` instead of `EXE` in other tutorial/solutions (like this https://dev.to/ngonidzashe/using-pyinstaller-to-package-kivy-and-kivymd-desktop-apps-2fmj).

```py
coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('examples-path\\demo\\touchtracer\\'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='touchtracer')
```